# Exporting an Eclipse project with jar file into a runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have an eclipse project that I am trying to export to a runnable jar.
My project uses an external jar.
The exported jar works fine expect for the functionality that uses the external jar.
I tried the extract and package libraries option.

Is there anything that I should add
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Tell us the build path of your project. How did you put the external library into that build path? Build path is accessible via right-click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path. There click on the tab Libraries.

Comment: your question is not clear, you mean the external jar is not part of the your project jar when you create a jar out of it,and you cant find the external jar inside your project jar lib folder

Comment: I addd the jar with two ways: 1st I tried adding external jar using the configure build path. I also tried with a lib folder containing the jar files as shown in http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java).

Comment: The problem is that the generated jar file does not perform the needed functionality that used the external jar. I could not find the external jar file also when I did the export. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

did you put external.jar in your libs folder? if not then you must :)
and if you you already did this and then you are exporting project then before exporting you should Right click on project --> properties--> java build path --> order and support --> check library which you are using

clean project(fresh build/installation)

it should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually didn't have a lib folder so I addded it and referenced the jar as shown in http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)
I then checked the library but I am still facing the same problem :(

Comment: go for fresh build(clean/remove bin folder then run project)